# Why is the wrong controller being called when I start my ASP.NET MVC2 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller called `MetricsController` with a single action method:

```
public class MetricsController
{
  public ActionResult GetMetrics(int id, string period)
  {
    return View("Metrics");
  }
}
```

I want to route calls to this controller like this:

`http://mysite/metrics/getmetrics/123/24h`

I've mapped an additional route in my `Global.asax.cs` like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Metrics",
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{period}",
  new { controller = "Metrics", action = "GetMetrics", id = 0, period = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I just added this to the default template project that Visual Studio 2010 creates.

When I run the application, instead of defaulting to the `HomeController`, it starts in the `MetricsController` instead.

Why is this happening? There's nothing in the url when I start the application that matches the url pattern specified in the `Metrics` route.

This is all being tried in Visual Studio 2010 using the built-in web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it matches first root, of course.

Thing is - when You provide default values - they become optional. If every one of routedata values are optional and route is first - it's guaranteed that it will hit first.

Something like this should work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Metrics",
  "Metrics/GetMetrics/{id}/{period}",
  //assuming id, period aren't supposed to be optional
  new { controller = "Metrics", action = "GetMetrics" }      
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! the penny has just dropped :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the defaults from your Metrics route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Metrics",
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{period}",
  new { controller = @"Metrics", action = "GetMetrics"}
);
```

With the default values MVC is able to map to the GetMetrics action in the Metric controller pretty much any URL that you pass to it.

Answer (score 1):

In short: it's using the `Matrics` route because it matches the `Matrics` route.

In long: The default route defines defaults for all the route components and all of the route components are optional. All that your `Metrics` route is doing is adding another optional route parameter with a default... it's basically no different from the default route because the whole route contains optional parameters.

If you want it to work, you need to differentiate your `Metrics` route from the default route.

E.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Metrics",
  "metrics/{action}/{id}/{period}",
  new { controller = @"Metrics", action = "GetMetrics", id = 0, period = "" }
);
```

HTHs,
Charles

Side note:

> There's nothing
>   in the url when I start the
>   application that matches the url
>   pattern specified in the Metrics
>   route.

Let's look at this from a different angle - what in the url matches the url pattern specified in the default route?